# Ubuntu 15.04 Kernel panic - Samsung Series 9

Tags: boot, kernel, uefi, 15.04, samsung

Samsung Series 9 Laptop crashes in ubuntu 13.04-15.10 and other Linux (debian, arch, freebsd).

Check: cleaned laptop, change the battery, change CPU cooler, memtest, temp.

kernel 3.11 - crashes every two weeks

kernel 3.16-4.1 - crashes everyday

fecit:

microcode updation

install UEFI and BIOS CSM

blacklist samsung_laptop

log:

```
> [19367.116180] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint 
> [19367.116196] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 1: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank 4: b200000000100402 
> [19367.116202] mce: [Hardware Error]: RIP !INEXACT! 33:<00007f8b4934c8b7> 
> [19367.116205] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 2824672b8e7 
> [19367.116211] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:306a9 TIME 14010118857 SOCKET 0 APIC 1 microcode 12 
> [19367.116213] mce: [Hardware Error]: Run the above through 'mcelog --ascii' 
> [19367.116216] mce: [Hardware Error]: Some CPUs didn't answer in synchronization 
> [19367.116218] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check: Invalid 
> [19367.116220] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal machine check on current CPU
```

How to fix the problem?

Comment: UP

 lspci -v

http://paste.ubuntu.com/11942100/


dmesg

http://paste.ubuntu.com/11942104/

syslog

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/11942114/

Answer (score 0):

FreeBSD is not Linux. If the laptop is crashing under both Linux and FreeBSD, then the problem is almost certainly not a software bug, since the code shared between the two kernels is negligible. Crashes under two OSes suggests that you've got bad hardware.

This hypothesis is further strengthened by a Web search on "machine check exception," which turns up many references, such as [this Wikipedia article,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-check_exception) which states:

> A **Machine Check Exception (MCE)** is a type of computer hardware error that occurs when a computer's central processing unit detects a hardware problem.

If this is a new computer, I suggest you return it to the store for a refund and describe the problem. If it's an old computer, it might be time to replace it; or perhaps you can take it to a shop for repairs.

Comment: why new kernels crashes often?

Comment: Software can exercise hardware differently. For instance, kernel A might result in a slightly higher CPU temperature than kernel B; or kernel A might use more of Instruction X, which is prone to lock up; or whatever. Back in the mid-1990s, a serious problem for Linux, OS/2, and other 32-bit OSes was RAM that worked fine with 16-bit DOS but failed when accessed using 32-bit access patterns. Your differences between kernels is likely something similar, albeit probably more subtle and harder to track down.